# How can I pass a variable from a controller to the routes file?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I would like my user to upload a file to my laravel site, submit the file, then be able to download that same file by clicking a link on another page. I know how to do everything except give the file name to the route specified on my html download link.

When a user uploads a file, their file is named by laravel using storeAs() to file1.png. The next file uploaded is file2.png, then file3.png, etc. The user  presses submit to store the file and is taken to a page view.blade.php. On this view.blade.php, I'd like for there to be a link that they can click and download the file they just uploaded.

Here is the code in my view.blade.php file:

```
<a href="/downloader">Download a file!</a>
<br>
Pic name = <?= $fileName ?>
```

Here is my "/downloader" route:

```
Route::get('/downloader', function() {
    return response()->download('../storage/app/uploads/'.$fileName);
});
```

From that html code, $fileName correctly prints the file name, so I know view.blade.php has the correct variable. I know the issue is that my routes file does not receive this variable $fileName, but I do not know how to pass this variable from this view.blade.php into the html download link so that my route can have the variable as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's how you do it:**

```
<a href="/downloader/{{ $filename }}"/>
```

But in order to be able to use the $filename variable above, you have to pass info about it via ViewData/ViewBag.

You do that simply by doing `view()->with(["filename" => "thefile.png"]);` in the route or controller.

---

And for the download route:

```
Route::get('/downloader/{filename}', function($filename) {
    return response()->download('../storage/app/uploads/'.$filename);
});
```

PS: This isn't the safest approach - it's highly suggested to add some form of verification, perhaps an alphanumeric token before file name.